# В 1с есть поле HTML документа, как можно записывать и получать данные в его localStorage?

Tags: 1с, localstorage

Пробую обратиться к localStorage и никак не получается.

```html
ОбъектHtml.localStorage.setItem("m", СтрJSON);
```

Пишу так, получаю сообщение, что значение не является значением объектного типа

Comment: Какая у вас версия платформы?

Comment: 8.3 (8.3.22.1923)

Comment: Методы объекта этого типа смотрели в синтакс-помощнике?